# Linearise $\max\{ y_{t-1} + a_t - z_t ,0\}$

Tags: constraint, linearization

I'm trying to linearise these constraints, but I am not able to do correctly do it.

$$y_t = \max\{ y_{t-1} + a_t - z_t, 0 \}  $$

My attempt was this:

\begin{align}y'_t &\geq a_t - z_t\\y'_t &\geq y^{'}_{t-1} + a_t - z_t \end{align}

Am I correct?

Additionally, I wanted to linearize this constraint:
$$y_t = y_{t-1} + a_t - z_t + \min\{ y'_{t-1} + a_t - z_t,0 \}$$

This one I am clueless on. I will appreciate if anyone could please give any leads on this.

Comment: Is this a maximization or minimization problem ?

Comment: I think the first one is a maximisation problem, and the second one is a min max problem.

Comment: @Kuifje can you help me here? the problem is also t dependent as you can see.

Comment: $y_t = \max \lbrace \dots \rbrace$ -- maximum with respect to what? The quantity inside the braces is a single value for fixed $t$.

Comment: Oh sorry, I missed, $y_t = \max \{ ...,0\}$

Comment: @Jimjamlorde please make your question as clear as possible and fix the typos/mistakes pointed by prubin.

Comment: @Kuifje Apologies, hope it is clear now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without relying on whether the solver "prefers" larger or smaller values of $y_t$, you can introduce a binary variable $\delta$ and the following constraints:\begin{align*}
y_{t} & \ge y_{t-1}+a_{t}-z_{t}\\
y_{t} & \ge0\\
y_{t} & \le y_{t-1}+a_{t}-z_{t}+M\delta\\
y_{t} & \le M(1-\delta).
\end{align*}
If $\delta=0$, this reduces to $y_t =y_{t-1} +a_t -z_t \ge 0$, while if $\delta=1$ it reduces to $y_t=0\ge y_{t-1} +a_t -z_t $.

For the second case, introduce a new variable $w_t$ to represent $\min\{ y'_{t-1} + a_t - z_t,0 \}$ and use the preceding with $y_t$ replaced by $w_t$ and with the four inequalities reversed.

Answer (score 5):

If you are *maximizing* $y_t$ (or any increasing function of $y_t$) and using "standard" inequalities, you  need something to preclude the solver from setting $y_t$ to $+\infty$. You can use the following constraints:
\begin{align*}
y_t &\le 0 +M(1-\delta) \tag{1}\\
y_t &\le y_{t-1}+a_t-z_t +M\delta \tag{2}\\
\delta &\in \{0,1\}
\end{align*}

If $\delta =1$, constraint $(2)$ is inactive and $y_t$ will take value $0$, since you are maximizing $y_t$. If $\delta=0$, constraint $(1)$ is inactive and $y_t$ will take value $y_{t-1}+a_t-z_t$.

For your constraint, the same philosophy holds. You can replace $\min(u)$ by a variable $x$ and add the following constraints:
\begin{align*}
x &\le u \tag{3}\\
x &\le 0 \tag{4}\\
x &\ge u +M(1-\omega) \tag{5}\\
x &\ge 0 +M\omega \tag{6}\\
\omega &\in \{0,1\}
\end{align*}

Comment: Would you know how to write this constraint in Pyomo, with $\delta$ ?

Comment: Additionally, how do I go about second part to my question, which is a linear combination, and I want to minimise.

Comment: now that I have updated the question, is it possible to help me with the second part too?

Comment: I don't fully understand the second part. What does it mean to "minimize a constraint" ?

Comment: If I have an equation such as $y = m + min(u)$, we want to linearise this equation, this is what I meant by minimise the constraint. Apologies for the lack of clarity.

Comment: you mean $\min(u,0)$ ?

Comment: yes this is what I mean

Comment: @Kuifje It might be clearer if you change $f(y_t)$ to $y_t$ at the start of your answer. Your current answer is correct if maximizing an *increasing* function $f()$ applied to $y_t$, but not if $f()$ is decreasing.

Comment: Yes indeed, thanks for pointing this out!